# How to select n-1 column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

We need to select n-l  column from n column in a Dataframe using python 
we have tried this method

Sample code

```
X = dataframe1[['Col1,Col2......n']]
```

Is there any other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pandas DataFrame `df` with column names `['Col1', 'Col2', ...]` you can do something like:

```
df.ix[:,'Col2':] # to select Col2, Col3, ...
```

or

```
df.ix[:,:'Col4'] # to select Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4
```

Comment: if we want to select till 4 column and we have 5 column in the dataframe so how can we select the column

Answer (score 1):

For recent queries, ix is deprecated:

```
df.loc[:, :"col[n-1]"] # To select columns except the last one. This is label based.
```

For index-based:

```
df.iloc[:, :(n - 1)] # To select columns except the last one. This is index based.
```

In general:

```
df.iloc[startRowNumber: endRowNumber, startColumnNumber: endColumnNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the solution is

df.ix[:,columnname1:columname2]

columnname1--> it is the first column you want to include
columnname2-->it is the last column where you want to select